# Keyboard not working after replacement?

Tags: laptop, keyboard

Not really sure how to troubleshoot the keyboard not working after replacing it on my Latitude E5520.

The mouse works (from the keyboard), the backlights are on, just no keys.  Actually they have registered a couple times but in general not working.  What is the next step?

Note:  I noticed that when I hit a key it turns my computer out of power saving mode.  So it seems the keystrokes are registered yet no keys can be typed.

Second Note: Plugged in USB keyboard.   It worked until Windows 7 loaded.  Then nothing.

Comment: Sounds like a possible loose connection. I'd verify the ribbon cable is seated completely. Does an external keyboard work normally?

Comment: @CharlieRB The hold down on the connection is crap.  I taped it down well so it doesn't move.  Do I just need to play with that?

Comment: That is most likely your problem. The hold down clamps the connection together to get good connectivity. A bad holder will cause all kinds of issues. Tape is not a good solution because it doesn't have clamping force. You will need to replace the hold down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talked to Dell.  They basically said that everything had to be installed correctly for me to get the functionality that I had.  And it was either a bad connection from the keyboard input module or just the entire keyboard itself - so new keyboard was defective.  Took a keyboard out of another Dell we had laying around and it worked fine with same connection ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the 3rd party drivers will cause malfunction.
Please check if you have installed any 3rd party keyboard drivers. Such as Logic or MS keyboard drivers.
(sorry I haven't sufficient reputation to leave a comment)